# Carrousel em php e mysql

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, carousel

Eu tenho um "upload de ficheiros" e precisava de as mostrar num carousel.
O caminho das imagens está guardado na base de dados e as imagens numa pasta, como é óbvio.
Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
  mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $img = $row['imagem'];
    echo "<div class='item active'>
      <img src='php/$img'>
    </div>";
    }
    ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

E quando eu vou testar as imagens aparecem umas em baixo das outras. E não consigo ver qual é o erro!

Eu fui buscar o código para o carrousel [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) e o carousel devia estar como mostra no exemplo do link que em cima referi, mas está desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso mesmo de ter isto pronto hoje e visto que nunca trabalhei com carousel em php e base de dados. Portanto eu vou colocar o [código da página toda](http://uploaded.net/file/n717i4h9).

E a pedido do Ricardo [aqui](http://uploaded.net/file/c1ns2jpl) fica o **html** renderizado

PS: Não fui eu que fiz isto portanto posso não poder responder a todas as questões que tenham.

Comment: Que plugin gera este carrosel, poste um print da página como esta e como deveria estar

Comment: @ricardo já editei e acho que mostrei tudo o que pediu

Comment: (off-topic) acho que não é necessário usar o snippet de exibição de código no caso da sua pergunta pois quando executamos não vemos o resultado real

Comment: Copie o código HTML renderizado do browser e cole aqui

Comment: @ricardo como assim renderizado?

Comment: Conseguiu fazer @BrunoGibellino ?

Comment: O html que aparece no browser

Comment: @ricardo já fiz edição na pergunta e adicionei o HTML renderizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, esta resposta é para quem quer fazer um carrossel mas não sabem quantas e quais imagens vão pôr, ou por outras palavras para fazer um carrossel com imagens da base de dados.

Eu vou explicar o mais detalhadamente possível. Pois eu também não percebo muito de carrossel.

Primeiro para que as imagens irem rodando, fazer com que apareça uma indicação de quantas imagens são (no meu caso são umas bolinhas) e para que apareça uma setas, uma para a esquerda, outra para a direita, que mudem de imagem, precisamos de uns plugins:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Podem ver mais detalhes sobre isto e de tudo o que vou explicar [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).

Depois para que as tais bolinhas referidas em cima precisamos de uma lista, mas como não sabemos quantas imagens são fazemos um contador:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");

    $ac = 0;
    $active = 'active';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='$ac' class='$active'></li>";
        $ac++;
        $active = '';
    }
?>
</ol>
```

Agora para as imagens, nós decidimos qual a imagem que aparece em primeiro utilizado `class = "active"` e os plugins acima tratam de rodar as imagens.
Porem estamos a usar um carrossel que nem sabemos quais são as imagens, portanto, como no site eu tenho um formulário que insere o caminho das imagens na base de dados e guarda as imagens no ficheiro basta irmos busca-las.
E para isso usamos:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");

    $active = 'active';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $img = $row['imagem'];
        echo "<div class='item $active'>
        <img src='php/$img' alt='Saber' width='460' height='345'>
      </div>";
      $active = '';
  }
?>
```

Como disse o active serve só para dizer qual a imagem que vai em primeiro portanto criamos uma variável a guardar "active" fora do *while* e dentro dele colocamos a variável vazia.

Por fim resta apenas definir as setas que à pouco falei para isso usamos:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

essas classes vêm dos plugins basta chama-los para que as setas funcionem.

E no final para que busque, mostre e rode as imagens da base de dados o código deve estar [assim](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzkdcftowfrz9ek/teste.php?dl=0).

Obrigado!

Answer (score 10):

Mediante a informação disponível na [fonte de onde extraíste o *carousel*](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp), através da análise ao código, a classe de CSS com o nome `active` só deve estar presente num único elemento, aquele que pretendes ter ativo ao carregar a página.

Depois o Plug-in trata de trocar a classe para o elemento seguinte e assim "criar" o *carousel*.

O teu código preparado para lidar com um único elemento ativo, e um indicador para cada imagem existem, tendo também em conta a ausência de imagens e/ou a presença de apenas uma imagem ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

// Estabelecer ligação à base de dados
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");

// Definir encoding
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");

// Recolher resultados
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");

/* Por cada resultado, preparar a saída
 */
$imagesHtml = '';

$indicatorDotsHtml = '';

$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $filename = $row['imagem'];

    // classe "active" apenas no primeiro elemento
    $active = $i==0 ? 'active' : '';

    // criar HTML para a imagem
    $imagesHtml.= '
    <div class="item '.$active.'">
        <img src="php/'.$filename.'" alt="'.$filename.'" />
    </div>';

    // criar HTML para o indicador da imagem
    $indicatorDotsHtml.= '
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.$active.'"></li>';
    
    $i++;
}


/* Preparar a saída para o navegador
 */
if (!empty($imagesHtml)) {

    /* Verificar se precisamos de navegação
     */
    $navHtml = '';

    if ($i>1) {

        $indicatorsHtml = '
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            '.$indicatorDotsHtml.'
        </ol>';

        $navHtml = '
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>';
    }

    /* Enviar saída para o navegador
     */
    echo '
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        '.$indicatorsHtml.'

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            '.$imagesHtml.'
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        '.$navHtml.'

    </div>';
}
?>
```

**Nota:**
É sempre útil consultar a documentação oficial do Plug-In para um melhor entendimento de como funciona e quais as opções ao nosso dispor:

## [Bootstrap - Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Answer (score 4):

O assunto é a subclass 'active' nas imagens. active só pode ser para uma imagem (neste caso é a primeira imagem). Na primeira iteração do while, o div terá a subclass active, os seguintes divs só serão criados com a class item. Com este código aqui, Funciona Corretamente:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");
$subclass = 'active';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$img = $row['imagem'];
echo "<div class='item $subclass'>
  <img src='php/$img'>
</div>";
$subclass='';
}
?>
```

Comment: Foi o que eu sugeri na minha resposta. Usei o $contador++ para regular esta questão, quando for a primeira, estará como active :D

Comment: muito bom a ideia

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from banners");
$classe = 'active';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$img = $row['imagem'];
echo "<div class='item" . $classe.">".
"<img src='php/$img'>
</div>";
$classe = '';
}
?>
```

*Lembre-se de adicionar as bibliotecas:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

*Simulei o código e funcionou, fiz o upload do código no dropbox para você ver o efeito: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwd64bsbo956i3x/teste.php?dl=0)

Comment: Agora não aparece as imagens

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Testa agora

Comment: para que serve aquela \ no echo?

Comment: @BrunoGibellino removi

Comment: Não mostra na mesma. O que será que está a interferir?

Comment: @BrunoGibellino você testou minha resposta? fiz um teste com imagens da internet e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @BrunoGibellino você adicionou as bibliotecas?

Comment: Não, Ricardo, não tenho bibliotecas. E as imagens que colocou foram buscadas da base de dados?

Comment: @BrunoGibellino você deve adicionar os três links de bibliotecas que postei em minha resposta (1 tag link e 2 script) entre as tags head do documento, assim como no meu arquivo de teste que postei em minha resposta.

Comment: @BrunoGibellino testou o exemplo que fiz upload no dropbox?

Comment: @BrunoGibellino vamos continuar no chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25919/discussion-between-bruno-gibellino-and-ricardo

Answer (score 2):

Tente desta forma:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","saber");
mysqli_set_charset($conexao,"utf-8");
$result = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from banners");

$contador = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result){

    $contador++;
    if($contador==0) $classe = ""; else $classe = "active";
    $img = "php/".$row['imagem'];

    echo "<div class='item {$classe}'>";
    echo "<img src='{$img}'>";
    echo "<div>";

}
```

## Note a forma de contactenação das variáveis `{$var}`.

Não esqueça de verificar se os CSS estão ativos e funcionando... jQuery também pode interferir, o bom é você posta o código todo, inclusive o topo com as requisições de jquery e css.

Comment: Não não consegui fazer não sei porque agora as imagens aparecem umas em cima das outras e não faz o efeito carousel

Comment: Verificou se o CSS e Jquery estão sendo importados da forma correta? Qual é o link que vejo o seu código funcionando?

Comment: Mas o class está definido como Active, para todos. dentro do while, e por este motivo, ficam todos ativos e não faz nenhuma transição. Modifiquei o código, tente dessa forma.

Comment: @BrunoGibellino Não esqueça que você precisa importar os CSS e jQuery para que funcione corretamente.

Comment: O erro pode ser tanto no CSS como no javascript (algum conflito talvez). Quando vc abre o console do Chrome apresenta algum tipo de erro?